# Smooth shader and subsurf shadow problem

Tags: modeling, uv

As you can see in the pictures I made a mesh and added loopcuts to it for the smooth face shading that it's using but there is an undesired shadow, which isn't seen from higher angles. When I apply subsurf it also gives a shadow but only on half of the selection...

without subsurf (just smooth face shading):

[image]

without subsurf (just smooth face shading) from different angle:

[image]

With subsurf:

[image]

[image]

file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the normals are incorrect. Select everything in edit mode and press Ctrl-N and that will recalculate the normals and fix it.

Comment: Thanks! I clicked the recalculate button on the left before but that didn't work, this did.